# Delta method for Poisson ratio

Tags: mathematical-statistics, asymptotics, delta-method

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be drawn from $Pois(\lambda)$ and $Y_1,...,Y_n$ from $Pois(\theta)$. I would like to find the asymptotic distribution of $$\frac{\overline X}{\overline X + \overline Y }$$ using delta method.

My difficulty with the problem is the following: while I understand that $\frac{\sqrt{n} (\overline X - \lambda)}{\sqrt{\lambda}} \sim N(0, 1)$ asymptotically, there seems to be no proper transformation function $g$ so that satisfies $\frac{\overline X}{\overline X + \overline Y } = g(\overline X)$, since the statistics is a function of both $\overline Y$ and $\overline X$.
I would appreciate thoughts on how delta method can be applied in this scenario.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [a vector version of the delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method#Multivariate_delta_method).  You have convergence of
$$\sqrt{n}(\bar X-\lambda,\, \bar Y-\theta)$$ to a bivariate Normal, and
the function
$$f(\bar X, \bar Y)=\frac{\bar X}{\bar X+\bar Y}$$
is differentiable (away from $\lambda=\theta=0$), so the delta method applies.

That isn't how I'd actually work out the answer, though. I would argue that conditional on $N=\sum_i (X_i + Y_i)$, the sum $\sum_i X_i$ is Binomial$(N, \lambda/(\lambda+\theta))$, so the ratio you're interested in is (conditionally) a binomial proportion, which is asymptotically Normal. Then I would note that $N/n\stackrel{a.s.}{\to}\lambda+\theta$, so that
$$\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{\bar X}{\bar X+\bar Y}-p\right)\stackrel{d}{\to} N\left(0, \frac{p(1-p)}{\lambda+\theta}\right)$$
where $p=\lambda/(\lambda+\theta)$

Answer (score 3):

This is just a visual comment on Thomas Lumley's answer (+1), illustrating it by simulation (blue) against his approximating normal distribution (red) using R

```
set.seed(2021)
lambda <- 2
theta  <- 5
n      <- 1000
cases  <- 10^5
Xbar   <- rpois(cases, n * lambda) / n
Ybar   <- rpois(cases, n * theta ) / n
ratio  <- Xbar / (Xbar + Ybar)
plot(density(ratio), col="blue")
curve(dnorm(x, lambda/(lambda+theta), sqrt(lambda*theta/(lambda+theta)^3/n)),
   from=min(ratio), to=max(ratio), col="red", add=TRUE)
```

[image]

As a couple of extra comments:

- There is a slight issue that there is always a positive probability that you get $\frac00$. So the actual ratio distribution is not well defined, though if $n\lambda$ and $n\mu$ are both large the probability of this is extremely small
- You do not have to take means, as the ratio of the sums $\frac{\sum X_i}{\sum X_i +\sum Y_i}$ has the same distribution
- Since the sums are themselves Poisson distributed, you might then, in a handwaving way, say that for large $\lambda$ and $\theta$ the distribution of the ratio $\frac{X}{X+Y}$ is approximately $N\left(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\theta}, \frac{\lambda\theta}{(\lambda+\theta)^3}\right)$ and that the probability of seeing $\frac00$ is only $e^{-(\lambda+\theta)}$

Comment: The probability of seeing 0/0 is $e^{-n(\lambda+\theta)}$, which is much smaller. You can define the ratio variable to have some other value when it's 0/0 and the asymptotic distribution won't be changed: 0 or 1 or 69/420 or anything you like.

Comment: why do you cube the denominator?

Comment: @Estimatetheestimators - see Thomas Lumley's answer with a variance of $\frac{p(1-p)}{\lambda+\theta}$ which needs to be scaled by $\frac1n$.  Then let $p = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\theta}$ and tidy up

Comment: Got it, ty so much @Henry.